# Certain unicode characters in Java don't show in JTextField

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, java-10

We recently converted the Oracle database of one of our customers from Windows-1252 to Unicode (I don't know how they still managed to live with that; they save many personal names).

Everything works well, except for some characters. It is the character `ṣ` (an s with a dot underneath), which let the problem enter our world.
As far as I know, when not specified, Java uses its logical fonts to find fonts which work on every OS (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html).

I set up a quick example, which is the one from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 * documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 * contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 * from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

/* TextDemo.java requires no other files. */
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Chartest extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    protected JTextField textField;
    protected JTextArea textArea;
    private final static String newline = "\n";

    public Chartest() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        // UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TextField.font", new Font("Arial",
        // Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        // Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(textField, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add(scrollPane, c);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = textField.getText();
        textArea.append(text + newline);
        textField.selectAll();

        // Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        // was a selection in the text area.
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new Chartest());

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The only thing I added is the following line:

```
// UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TextField.font", new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

Without this line, `ṣ` becomes a square, when typing into the text field. If you uncomment this line, it works. Looking into `fontconfig.properties.src` in the Java lib folder, all logical fonts point to fonts, which can display the `ṣ`: Times, Courier, Arial. I renamed the file to `fontconfig.properties` and changed everything to `Arial` to override the defaults. It didn't change anything.
This does not work, as well:

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TextField.font", new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

Although Dialog obviously references to Arial in the `fontconfig.properties.src`.
What am I overlooking? I'm on Java 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rendering of the logical fonts seems to a field of mysteries. In one test run, I got correct rendering of the characters in question within the `JTextArea` but not within the `JTextField` while `textArea.getFont()==textField.getFont()` evaluated to `true`!

The `fontconfig.properties.src` refers to `Arial`, but it also contains this line:

```
exclusion.alphabetic=0700-1e9f,1f00-2017,2020-20ab,20ad-20b8,20bb-20bc,20be-f8ff
```

and `ṣ` and `Ṣ` (`U+1e63` and `U+1e62`) are exactly within that range.

I don’t known where these clearly “alphabetic” characters are supposed to end up when being excluded here. [This document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html) just states:

> This is used if a font with a large character repertoire needs to be placed early in the search sequence (for example, for performance reasons), but some characters that it supports should be drawn with a different font instead.

But I have no idea why these characters shouldn’t be rendered with the first font configured for “alphabetic” and which other font in the search sequence is supposed to render them.

Also, this range looks quiet arbitrary, i.e. it implies that while `Ṣ` and `ṣ` are in the excluded range, `Ạ` and `ạ` are not and can be rendered correctly.

When you turn this line into a comment, i.e.

```
#exclusion.alphabetic=0700-1e9f,1f00-2017,2020-20ab,20ad-20b8,20bb-20bc,20be-f8ff
```

the problem disappears.

I have the feeling that the original exclusion clause caused the rendering to end up at the embedded Lucida font, which can not render these characters. In JDK 11, this exclusion line still exists and it’s updated version:

```
exclusion.alphabetic=0700-1cff,1d80-1e9f,1f00-2017,2020-20ab,20ad-20b8,20bb-20bc,20be-f8ff
```

still covers `ṣ` and `Ṣ` (`U+1e63` and `U+1e62`). But the Lucida fonts have been removed, hence, the hardcoded references to these fonts within the AWT code must have been removed as well.

As a net result of the changes made between JDK 10 and JDK 11, the characters `ṣ` and `Ṣ` are rendered correctly.

So the bottom line is, instead of trying to fix the AWT configuration of JDK 10, you can also simply update to JDK 11.

This applies to both, OpenJDK 11 and Oracle JDK 11. Their font config files only differ in the licence header comment…

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, this works perfectly. Can't upgrade to JDK11 at the moment, but commenting out the line is sufficient. This gave me a headache. What a chaos.